# How many average flips to get an equal amount of H and T

Tags: probability

Let's say the first time I flip the coin, I get HT. I would then erase the data and start over because I got an equal amount of Heads and Tails.

The second attempt I get HHHTTHTT. At that point, I stop because I have an equal amount of heads and tails. I then start over.

I flip the coin until I get an equal amount of heads and tails, then stop and start over. What would be the average amount of flips needed to get an even number of heads and tails? Sometimes it only takes two flips. Other times it can take many more flips. Consider the coin is fair.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk

Comment: I cannot find the answer in those two links. The second link seems to imply that sometimes it might take infinite flips. BTW, I am not doing this for gambling. It is to see if a part of my philosophy works.

Comment: I also read on here about how many possible head or tails is possible in a row. The answer seemed like it must be finite. Would this also not mean that any particular pattern must be finite? And it would take a particular pattern to avoid landing on heads and tails and equal amount of time.  I would think then that there must always be a finite amount of flips in order to get an equal amount of heads and tails.